# Filtering on index in dask dataframe is not any faster than filtering on any other column

Tags: dataframe, indexing, dask, parquet

I'm loading a dask dataframe from a parquet collection of around 1300 parquet files, total of 250 milions entries. Dataset is a time series and has a datetime index.

In general I'm pretty happy with performance of queries considering the size of the dataset (6-7 min approx).

One thing I don't understand is why index filtering is no faster than any other column filtering.

What I mean is that if I take a slice of the ddf on timestamp (index) or if I take a slice based on any other field, the time it takes to compute the dataframe is basically identical.

Am I doing something wrong? I would have imagined filter on index would be much faster

Tried to reindex a second time but didn't help.

I've checked suggestions on this post: https://www.coiled.io/blog/dask-set-index-dataframe

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

dask.config.set(scheduler=dask.multiprocessing.get)
ddf = dd.read_parquet(data_lake + asset_class, engine='pyarrow',columns=['Close','Open','Symbol', 'TradeHigh', 'TradeLow', 'CloseCumulativeVolume', 'CloseDate', 'CloseCumulativeValue', 'TradeCount'])

q1_21 = ddf['2021-01-01':'2021-04-01'].compute()
#Wall time: 2min 59s

df = ddf.loc[ddf['Symbol'].str.contains('MSFT|TSLA')].compute()
#Wall time: 3min 2s
```

Comment: can you include any code? the first thing that comes to mind to me is - have you persisted your data on a cluster? if not, I'd guess that the vast majority of the time is  in reading all those files, not in selecting data. I'd bet that the selection *is* faster, but that the selection time is orders of magnitude smaller than the time it takes to open and read metadata and selected columns for 1300 parquet files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado apologies, was away for the holidays and completely lost track of this thread. I have added the code I'm using to the question. I understand your point there, maybe I'll try and use a different approach to query the dataset.